# Change wifi passphrase on windows 10 (No local admin, wifi not currently in range)

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

Seemingly simple question:
How can I  change the passphrase for a wifi, stored on my windows 10 PC, without removing the entire profile ("Forget network").

Constraints/preferences (see background):

- I don't have local admin.
- The wifi is not in range.
- I'd like to avoid removing the profile and adding it again.

Background:
I'm on a corporate issued laptop, where I don't have local admin.
I regularly work at a partners site, hence using their wifi.
Connecting the partner wifi is allowed by our policies - I can add a new wifi profile - but it is an elaborate process, with specific security settings for the partner site, that are not well documented, (and I was too lazy to document it for my self, last time, when I spent half a day on getting it right.)
The partner have now change the wifi passphrase, so I need to do that too.
Going to the partner site, getting in range of the wifi, will get me blocked due to repeated connection attempts with invalid passphrases, hence the desire to fix this without having the wifi in range.

---

**FAILS:**

It seems that the following should to the trick, but it fails:

```
C:\Users\user>netsh wlan set profileparameter name=WIFIPROFILENAME keyMaterial=MYPASSWORD

The inputed parameter is invalid to the original profile setting.


C:\Users\user>
```

Comment: I would be shocked if Windows tried more then once after not being able to connect to an access point.

Answer (score 0):

Click the Network icon on the lower right corner of your screen.
Click Network settings.
Click Manage Wi-Fi settings.

You can share and forget but you can't make changes to the network profile unless your connected or in range of it.

There is this video a user put together on managing your wireless networks using a third party tool or COMMAND PROMPT tools that might do what your looking for.

[How To Manage You Wireless Networks In Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCiGpKLIYBs)

It is stupid windows didn't leave the Manage Wireless Networks button in the connection section but I guess they think it is cleaner and safer to add these things if you remove and readd them.

Comment: Run shell:::{1FA9085F-25A2-489B-85D4-86326EEDCD87} to quickly manage wireless network settings

Comment: @davidmneedham No luck with that here. Nothing happens.